# gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning {PATH}/env/bin/gunicorn: Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, django

After creating my gunicorn.service file, I ran

```
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.service
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.service
```

However, I receive the following error below. This is the log returned after running

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service
```

Error Log

```
ubuntu@ip-000-00-00-00:~/webapp/appname$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-07-18 21:28:42 UTC; 19min ago
  Process: 11634 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/webapp/appname/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapp/appname/appname.sock appname.wsgi:application
Main PID: 11634 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jul 18 21:28:42 ip-000-00-00-00 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn service.
Jul 18 21:28:42 ip-000-00-00-00 systemd[11634]: gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Jul 18 21:28:42 ip-000-00-00-00 systemd[11634]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/ubuntu/webapp/appname/env/bin/gunicorn: Permission denied
Jul 18 21:28:42 ip-000-00-00-00 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 18 21:28:42 ip-000-00-00-00 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Here is the permission to the gunicorn file in the that is in the `/home/ubuntu/webapp/appname/env/bin/gunicorn` path

```
ubuntu@ip-000-00-00-00:~/webapp/appname/env/bin$ ls -l gunicorn
-rwxrwx--x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 257 Jul 13 07:20 gunicorn
```

not sure why I'm getting permissions denied. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had a web application (frontend + backend); and one day the frontend couldn't access the backend correctly. gunicorn was displaying almost the same logs as you. I had to put an https certificate (because it had expired) on my site to get everything working again